# please evaluate this integral : $\int_0^tx^{a-1}e^{-x}~dx$

Tags: integration

> $$\int_0^tx^{a-1}e^{-x}~dx.$$

I need help evaluating the above, step by step would help.

Thanks

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5E%28a-1%29).

Comment: It looks like gamma function. You can look at from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: Is $a$ supposed to be a positive integer? If so, then you use induction and by-parts integration to find the antiderivatives of $x^ne^{-x}$. If not, then you will have to settle with just giving the function a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general manner, the antiderivative of your integrand is -Gamma[a, x] which is the incomplete Gamma function (as told by user40615). The result of the integration between 0 and t is  (Gamma[a] - Gamma[a, t]) provided that Re[a] > 0.

If a is a positive integer, then, as suggested by anon, integrate by parts [u = x^(a-1)] and you will find quite simple recurrence relations. For axample, the antiderivative of x^(a-1) Exp[-x] is - x^(a-2) Exp[-x] + (a-1) times the antiderivative of  x^(a-2) Exp[-x]. I suppose that this is the case you are working one.

Suppose that n is an integer; you will easily show that the integral writes as (n-1)! + Exp[-t] P[n-1,x] where the latest represents a polynomial of degree (n-1).

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle{\large \int_{0}^{t}x^{\alpha - 1}{\rm e}^{-x}\,{\rm d}x
=
\gamma\left(\alpha,t\right).\quad}$
$\Re\alpha > 0.\quad$ $\gamma\ $ is one of the ${\it\mbox{incomplete gamma functions}}$.

See G&R ${\bf 8.350}.1$ ( $7^{\underline{\rm a}}$ ed., pag. 899 ).